# Laravel 7,8- Using AND or OR Operator in @if... @endif does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel project where some users are to be shown some data based on their Roles.

Say There are some roles in a list like r001,r002,r003,r004

Suppose I want to show add button to users with roles r002,r004

Here is my **blade file**

```
@if($userrole == '002' || $userrole == '004' )
  <button>Add Data </button>
@endif
```

The end result is, it shows that button to **everyone**, even if their role is different.

How can I overcome this limitation ?

Comment: So is the role named `r002` or `002`? What does `$userrole` contain? `{{dd($userrole)}}`

Comment: You are missing r while writing '002' and '004' in the condition.

Comment: please check everything again, may be you are missing something

Comment: @brombeer That is a typo

Comment: @KaleemShoukat That is a typo

Comment: check what you are getting in $userrole by using dd($userrole);
if that contains r002 or r003 then condition should work fine.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and correct the typo so we can see your original code. Better use copy/paste next time

Comment: @brombeer I tried editing, but it wont let me, because another edit queue is in place.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat I am getting rol as r005, but it is still showing the button

Comment: @if($userrole === 'r002' || $userrole === 'r004' ) try with it.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat Nope. That does not work either

Comment: Might help if you do e.g. `$userrole === '002'` to prevent any unintended casting

Comment: @apokryfos That didnt work either

Comment: then you need to share the contents of `$userrole` e.g. do `<?php dd($userrole) ?>` somewhere in that view and let us know the exact result

Comment: It shows `rol005`

Answer (score 0):

Check $userrole value using {{$userrole}} in your blade file, If $userrole has value r005 than you have to write like

```
@if($userrole == “r002” || $userrole == “r004” ) 
 <button>Add Data </button> 
@endif
```

Comment: Nope. Didnt work either. Also, I have this issue while checking conditions with numbers (digits) as well.